# Ruby group_by return array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a block of code that looks like

```
runs.this_month.group_by(&:week).each do |week,runs|
  puts 'week' + week
  puts runs.size
end
```

Right now it just returns
`week00`
`1`
`week 03`
`1`

What I am hoping to have this loop generate is an object that has 0's if that week has no runs. For example, if I have the month of January, and there is one run the first week,no runs the second week, one run the 3rd week,and no runs the last week, ideally it would return something that looks like

`[1,0,1,0]`

I think my issue is with the group_by() enumerable not knowing how many weeks there are in a month for example.

Also FWIW the this_month scope looks for all `runs` with :created_at this month. That bit works as expected and returns a group of all of the runs from this month.

edit1:
This is sloppy, but seems to be working:

```
month = [0,0,0,0]
weeks = [0,1,2,3]
runs.this_month.group_by(&:week).each do |week,runs|
  if weeks.include? (week[0].to_i)
    month[week.to_i] = runs
  end
end
```

working means month looks like
`[ActiveRecord...,0,ActiveRecord...,0]`

Comment: The `group_by` is certainly part of your problem.  What have you tried to resolve that issue?  Simplest way would be to just add empty entries for the weeks that are missing.

Comment: @NickVeys- I have tried checking the value of "week" (00 or 03 in this case) against an array of [0,1,2,3] to see if that week belongs there, if so put the run in that element's position...if that makes sense

Comment: Ok, did that help?  The code you posted just prints things.  It's confusing because you are asking for something when it looks like your code doesn't even attempt to do it.  You get *much* better responses on this site if you try but fail, and then ask for help with your current solution.

Comment: Yeah code doesn't work well in comments, just edit your question.

Comment: yup, sorry about that. Should have formatted my question more clearly. The edit has a bit more clarification

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `weeks` are integers 0, 1, 2, 3.

```
default_stats = { 0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [] }
runs.this_month.group_by(&:week).reverse_merge(default_stats)
```